# Use vector images programmatically (e.g. for UIBarButtonItem)

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, asset-catalog

I am currently playing around with vector images in Swift. I am trying to add a UIBarButtonItem to a navigation bar programmatically using a vector image from asset catalog. I am adding the item to a viewControllers navigation item:

```
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "vectorImage"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
```

The bar button item appears in the navigation bar as expected, but the image is not scaled. It's always shown in the resolution of the vector PDF in the asset catalog. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Vector Image (.pdf vector) is not supported in runtime.
It only makes @1x, @2x, @3x .png images in build time from the vector image you provide . So it is not fully in vector paths. You might want to read this article: [USING VECTOR IMAGES IN XCODE 6](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)